# increment string date in jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I have a date as string

```
var myOldDate = "2019-10-25";
```

I want add **90 days** to my string date, apparently it's complicated, is there any easy way to increment date in JQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) Also, jQuery is not a date manipulation library. Consider using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) or [datefns](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var myOldDate = "2019-10-25";
var date = new Date(myOldDate);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 90);
console.log(date.toISOString().split('T')[0])
```

Comment: @mojtabash glad to help